# How can I change the space between a table title and its page number in the list of tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, gap

In the list of tables, I have to change the space between a table title and its page number. I was able to change the space between the table number and the table header thanks to the codes I found here, but the above problem still persists. Actually, I found a code like the below:

```
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{4em}

\makeatother
```

However, this code only keeps constant the gap between dots and the page number. If the title of the table is long, words can cross the limit. Example,

[image]

I want the word "ratios" line up with the dots. Or let the word "ratios" be on the next line, but let the word "SPN" line up with the dots. Also, the same problem applies to the table of contents and the list of figures.

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. Otherwise we have no idea what you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (by adding the command: `\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4.2em}`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[left=3cm, top=3cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize List of Tables\hfill\vspace{24pt}}
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{0.25}
\newlength\mylength
\cftsetindents{table}{0cm}{0.9cm}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\tablename~}
\settowidth\mylength{\cfttabpresnum}
\addtolength\cfttabnumwidth{\mylength}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{4.2em}% -> Here!!!
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{4.2em}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{sloppypar}
\listoftables
\end{sloppypar}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{-2cm}
{\noindent
$
\begin{array}{llr}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\textbf{Table No}& \hspace{-0.2cm}\textbf{Table Title} &  \hspace{9cm}\textbf{Page No}
\end{array}
$}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Mean SSIM results for 20 traditional images with different SPN ratios ranging from bla bla bla}
xxx
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. The solution worked.

Comment: Welcome @Burak ... Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the following MWE will be enough.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[left=3cm, top=3cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill\bfseries\normalsize List of Tables\hfill\vspace{24pt}}
\renewcommand{\cfttabdotsep}{0.25}
\newlength\mylength
\cftsetindents{table}{0cm}{0.9cm}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\tablename~}
\settowidth\mylength{\cfttabpresnum}
\addtolength\cfttabnumwidth{\mylength}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{4.2em}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\listoftables
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{-2cm}
{\noindent
$
\begin{array}{llr}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\textbf{Table No}& \hspace{-0.2cm}\textbf{Table Title} &  \hspace{9cm}\textbf{Page No}
\end{array}
$}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Mean SSIM results for 20 traditional images with different SPN ratios ranging from bla bla bla}
xxx
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

For the above example, YAP is as follows:

Page 1
[image]

Page 2
[image]